# R reshape cast error

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to follow the following example for the reshape package but am getting an error

```
smithsm <- melt(smiths)

smithsm

 subject variable value
1 John Smith     time  1.00
2 Mary Smith     time  1.00
3 John Smith      age 33.00
4 Mary Smith      age    NA
5 John Smith   weight 90.00
6 Mary Smith   weight    NA
7 John Smith   height  1.87
8 Mary Smith   height  1.54

cast(smithsm, time + subject ~ variable)
```

This gives the error "Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: time". Does anyone know what is causing this error? The above is taken word for word from an example

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good error message really, you have no column in your data.frame called `time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `smithsm` dataset doesn't have `time` column.  It is not clear what the expected `wide` form is.  Perhaps, this helps

```
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(smithsm, subject~variable, value.var='value')
 #    subject age height time weight
 #1 John Smith  33   1.87    1     90
 #2 Mary Smith  NA   1.54    1     NA
```

#### data

```
 smithsm <- structure(list(subject = c("John Smith", "Mary Smith", "John Smith", 
 "Mary Smith", "John Smith", "Mary Smith", "John Smith", "Mary Smith"
 ), variable = c("time", "time", "age", "age", "weight", "weight", 
 "height", "height"), value = c(1, 1, 33, NA, 90, NA, 1.87, 1.54
 )), .Names = c("subject", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```